# Can we calculate how long the data is stored on the node based on Pruning Index Value?

Tags: zebra-savanna

Is it possible to calculate how long the data is stored on the node based on Pruning Index Value?

Comment: The best way to ensure data is stored permanently is to use a Chronicle Permanode.